# How to find out who creates the ec2 instance on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

There are a list of EC2 instances in my organization aws account. I'd like to find out who creates these instances. These instances don't have any tag or meta data telling me who creates them.

I am using `aws ec2 describe-instances` which returns a list of instances information including a field `OwnerId` and `RequesterId`. Do these fields refer to the user id? How can I map these id to an user id? Or is there another way to find out who created them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon EC2 instances, once launched, are owned by the AWS Account. They are *not* associated with the user that launched it.

You can use [AWS CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html) to view all API calls made to the account. This will include a `RunInstances` command that launched the instance. The CloudTrail record will include details of the user/credentials that were used to issue the command.

The fields you mentioned do not contain this information:

- **OwnerId:** The ID of the AWS account that owns the reservation.
- **RequesterId:** The ID of the requester that launched the instances on your behalf (for example, AWS Management Console or Auto Scaling).

Comment: CloudTrail wont record the history calls. If there is an existing ec2 instance, CloudTrail can't know who create that instance.

Comment: Sort of. You need to activate a CloudTrail to capture and keep your history, but the past 7 days is available to everyone. See: [AWS CloudTrail Event History Now Available to All Customers](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/08/aws-cloudtrail-event-history-now-available-to-all-customers/)

Comment: My instance was created a few weeks ago so it can't be found by cloud trail. Is there other way to get that? what does OwnerId and RequesterId mean in ec2 description data?

Comment: No, you will not be able to find that information if CloudTrail was not activated. The definition of those fields is shown in my answer, above.

Comment: I think these two ID are what I need right? How do these ID map to user in IAM?

Comment: The `OwnerID` is the AWS Account number, not a user. The `RequesterId` is only used if the instance was launched by another AWS service. It does not show user information. I know that the field names sound appropriate, but they are not providing the information you seek.

Comment: What is `AWS Account number`? Is it a user account?

Comment: An AWS Account is used for billing and security purposes. All your usage of AWS is within an AWS Account. A login can only view/create services related to that account, and all costs for those services will be charged for the account as a whole. It is not associated with users.